# On a non-const object, why won't C++ call the const version of a member function with public-const and private-non-const overloads?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, private-methods, public-method, function-qualifier

```
class C
{
public:
    void foo() const {}
private:
    void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.foo();
}
```

MSVC 2013 doesn't like this:

```
> error C2248: 'C::foo' : cannot access private member declared in class 'C'
```

If I cast to a `const` reference, it works:

```
const_cast<C const &>(c).foo();
```

Why can't I call the `const` member function on the non`const` object?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the standard:

> 13.3.3 If a best viable function exists and is unique, overload resolution succeeds and produces it as the result.
>   Otherwise overload resolution fails and the invocation is ill-formed. **When overload resolution succeeds, and
>   the best viable function is not accessible (Clause 11) in the context in which it is used, the program is
>   ill-formed.**

Comment: I.e. lookup semantics in C++ applies as if access checks did not exist. Then access checks are applied. Access checks do not affect visibility and choice, only permission.

Comment: So code external to the class can break by adding a private member function. External code depends on class internals.

Comment: @usr But you get a compiler error. If it weren't this way, code's behaviour could change silently when you change the access of a member function.

Comment: @juanchopanza causing a compiler error is a breaking change. If C is in a library that library must be carefully naming its private members to not cause depending code to break when the library updates.

Comment: @usr Changing the behaviour is also a breaking change. Better to fail early. But in real code you shouldn't have overloads with different access.

Answer (score 24):

The object is not `const`, so the non-`const` overload is a better match. Overload resolution happens before access checking. This ensures that overload resolution is not inadvertently changed by changing the access of a member function.

Comment: And the reasoning is that the designers felt it would be error prone to have lookup and resolution depend on access checking; changing a method from public to private could result in uses of that function silently switching to some other function without that being the intention.